# ThymeLeaf 3 + Spring 4 [ ERROR: Can not resolve object in the view ]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**Hello,**

*I'm doing the simple web app with Spring , Hibernate, ThymeLeaf etc. I have some experience with Spring 4 and Hibernate 5 but ThymeLeaf is used by me the first time. I need to get inputted values into the Form Object and save in POJO (session, DB) and on the next page to show inputted value. Hope you can help me.*

I'm trying to fix it for a few days. So let I show your my sources and than an error.

**WebConfig.class**

```
/**
 * Holds resolver's prefix.
 */
private static final String PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/templates/";

/**
 * Holds resolver's postfix.
 */
private static final String SUFFIX = ".html";

/**
 * Static resources location
 */
private static final String RESOURCE_LOCATION = "/resources/styles/";

/**
 * Static resources location
 */
private static final String RESOURCE_HANDLER_STYLE = "/resources/styles/**";

/**
 * Holds resolver's encoding.
 */
private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

/**
 * Application context
 */
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

/**
 * Sets the applicationContext.
 *
 * @param applicationContext the application context.
 */
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

/**
 * Gets viewResolver
 *
 * @return ViewResolver
 */
@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(getTemplateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF8);
    return resolver;
}

/**
 * Gets TemplateEngine
 *
 * @return the engine.
 */
private TemplateEngine getTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(getTemplateResolver());
    return engine;
}

/**
 * Gets resolver.
 *
 * @return resolver.
 */
private ITemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix(PREFIX);
    resolver.setSuffix(SUFFIX);
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCacheable(true);
    return resolver;
}

/**
 * Sets the path to css,image and js files.
 *
 * @param registry the registry to set handlers of resource folder.
 */
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler(RESOURCE_HANDLER_STYLE).addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATION)
            .setCachePeriod(86400);
}
```

**ClientForm.class**

```
@NotNull
private int clientId;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 45)
private String clientName;

@NotNull
private boolean clientAgreement;

public String toString() {
    return "ClientForm [ id = " + this.clientId + ", name = " + this.clientName
            + ", agreement = " + this.clientAgreement + " ]";
}
```

**Controller**

```
private static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "login";

@Autowired
ClientService clientService;

@GetMapping(value = {"/", "/login", "/home", "/index"})
public String getLoginForm(Model model) {
    logger.info("GET request to " + LOGIN_PAGE);
    model.addAttribute("clientForm", "BLABLABLA");
    return LOGIN_PAGE;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/")
public String checkClientInfo(@ModelAttribute(value = "clientForm") @Valid ClientForm clientForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    logger.info("POST request to " + LOGIN_PAGE);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("POST request to " + LOGIN_PAGE + " has some errors. Check trace.");
        return LOGIN_PAGE;
    }
    logger.info("POST request to " + LOGIN_PAGE + " is done successfully. You are redirecting to /order page.");
    return "redirect:/order";
}
```

**login.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title>Online Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/resources/styles/style.css}">
</head>
<body onload="document.clientForm.clientName.focus();">

<form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${clientForm}" name="clientForm" action="#" method="POST">
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to Online Shop</h1>

        <input type="text" th:name="*{clientName}" name="clientName" value='' placeholder="Enter your name"/>
        <h1 data-th-text="${clientForm}"></h1>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxOption" value="isChecked"/>I agree with the terms of service</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**And my error (I have to admite that th: is working well, url to css is valid):**
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU2xh.png)

*and my gradle.build script:*
[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDRW.png)

Hope someone have any good idea.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation in the `getLoginForm()` looks wrong. The proper way is to send an object of your **form** class (**ClientForm.class**) to the view.

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/", "/login", "/home", "/index"})
public String getLoginForm(Model model) {
    logger.info("GET request to " + LOGIN_PAGE);
    model.addAttribute("clientForm", new ClientForm());
    return LOGIN_PAGE;
}
```

For detailed reference check the demo spring project [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

Comment: As I did. I save attribute in the session. Isn't it?

Comment: Please try to send new ClientForm() in your model. Change "BLABLABLA" to new ClientForm()

Comment: Oh, I found , I did it before nothing changed. Anyway thank you. When I deployed my application it works but didnt show elements with wrong attributes.